# "Bob the builder lives in Australia" or "Bob, the builder, lives in Australia"?

Tags: grammar, commas

Is this correct:

> "Bob the builder lives in Australia"

or should I use commas like so:

> "Bob, the builder, lives in Australia"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Without context, it is impossible to say which is "correct"; both are acceptable appositive forms, but they mean different things. If you are learning English, I recommend visiting our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour), where I have [provided an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/9657/21)  to a similar question.

Comment: Related: *[Meaning of “My friend, who lives in Paris, is a teacher” with and without commas](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104059)*, *[Comma usage (ex. His sister, Anne, was not feeling well.)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261991)*, and a number of others.

Comment: The first one would be incorrect, assuming you're talking about the popular kid's hero -- it should be _Bob the **B**uilder_.

Comment: Neither, Bob the Builder lives in Britain. See the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: You brilliant man, @David.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the context. If you meant "Bob the **B**uilder" as a noun then you don't need to use commas. For example:

> Mickey Mouse lives in Canada.

But if that Mickey mouse was a carpenter then it would have been something like

> Mickey Mouse, the carpenter, lives in Canada.

Comment: Another  (perhaps better) example: "Winnie the Pooh lives in the Hundred Acre Wood", but "Winnie, the cat, [lives in Indiana](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/17972624/ns/health-pet_health/t/cat-saves-family-poisonous-fumes/)", and "Winnie the Pooh, the bear, lives in the Hundred Acre Wood"

Comment: That's a great example @Chris H